# Combining Materials/Maps?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, normal-map

I'm relatively new to Blender and have been using it to convert models from MMD and XPS format to SMD/DMX for Source Filmmaker.

My problem right now is that Source doesn't seem to recognize more than 2 (or possibly three) texture maps applied to a single area. The model I'm working on uses up to four, including the diffuse map, bump map, specular map, and light map. I can essentially only set up SFM to recognize the diffuse and bump map, but when that happens the model obviously loses a ton of detail those extra two maps provide.

Is there any way to combine the extra maps to import just two into Source without losing all (or at least as much) of the data? I'm not sure if I'm using the right terms here, but I hope someone can understand me!